# Fetch the occurrences of particular words in particular column of a table

Tags: mysql

I have near about 200 words. I want to see how many times those words occurred in a column of a table.

e.g: say we have table test with column statements which has two rows.

1. How are you. It's been long since I met you.
2. I am fine how are you.

Now I want to find the the occurrences of words "you" and "how". Output should be something like:

```
word          count
you            3
how            2
```

since "you" has 3 and how has 2 occurrences in the two rows.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1. Split the phrase and put all items in a different table;
2. Remove all ponctuation;
3. Make a `select` using the created table and the words that you want to identify.

Comment: are you suggesting to do this using php? I don't want to make use of php. I want to do this only in php. Is it possible? If you can do this is mysql only, please can you give an example.

Comment: This is impossible with only MySQL as it doesn't have string splitting functions. But it's probably possible to write your own function. Something like this: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: @Minras: That's simply not true.  Using a loop and [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) can explode a string on a delimiter.  It would certainly be *easier* in a language like Perl or PHP, but you can do just about anything purely in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to write a little [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) to give me the number of times one string appears in another with some allowances for:

- upper and lower case
- common punctuation

I would then create a table with all of the words that I wish to search with i.e. your 200 list. Then use the function to count the number of occurrences of each word in every phrase, put that in a inline view and then sum the results up by search word.

Hence:

**User Defined Function**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `get_word_count`(phrase VARCHAR(500),word VARCHAR(255), delimiter VARCHAR(1)) RETURNS int(11)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
 DECLARE cur_position INT DEFAULT 1 ; 
 DECLARE remainder TEXT;
 DECLARE cur_string VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE delimiter_length TINYINT UNSIGNED;
 DECLARE total INT;
 DECLARE result DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE string2 VARCHAR(255);

 SET remainder = replace(phrase,'!',' ');
 SET remainder = replace(remainder,'.',' ');
 SET remainder = replace(remainder,',',' ');
 SET remainder = replace(remainder,'?',' ');
 SET remainder = replace(remainder,':',' ');
 SET remainder = replace(remainder,'(',' ');

 SET remainder = lower(remainder);

 SET string2 = concat(delimiter,trim(word),delimiter);
 SET delimiter_length = CHAR_LENGTH(delimiter);
 SET cur_position = 1;

 WHILE CHAR_LENGTH(remainder) > 0 AND cur_position > 0 DO
    SET cur_position = INSTR(remainder, delimiter);
    IF cur_position = 0 THEN
        SET cur_string = remainder;
    ELSE
        SET cur_string = concat(delimiter,LEFT(remainder, cur_position - 1),delimiter);
    END IF;
    IF TRIM(cur_string) != '' THEN
        set result = result + (select instr(string2,cur_string) > 0);
    END IF;
    SET remainder = SUBSTRING(remainder, cur_position + delimiter_length);
 END WHILE;

 RETURN result;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You might have to play with this function a little depending on what allowances you need to make for punctuation and case. Hopefully you get the idea here though!

**Populate tables**

```
create table search_word
(id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
 word varchar(250) not null
);

insert into search_word (word) values ('you');
insert into search_word (word) values ('how');
insert into search_word (word) values ('to');
insert into search_word (word) values ('too');
insert into search_word (word) values ('the');
insert into search_word (word) values ('and');
insert into search_word (word) values ('world');
insert into search_word (word) values ('hello');

create table phrase_to_search
(id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
phrase varchar(500) not null
);

insert into phrase_to_search (phrase) values ("How are you. It's been long since I met you");
insert into phrase_to_search (phrase) values ("I am fine how are you?");
insert into phrase_to_search (phrase) values ("Oh. Not bad. All is ok with the world, I think");
insert into phrase_to_search (phrase) values ("I think so too!");
insert into phrase_to_search (phrase) values ("You know what? I think so too!");
```

**Run Query**

```
select word,sum(word_count) as total_word_count
from
(
select phrase,word,get_word_count(phrase,word," ") as word_count
from search_word
join phrase_to_search
) t
group by word
order by total_word_count desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT SUM(total_count) as total, value
FROM (

SELECT count(*) AS total_count, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(x.value,'?',''),'.',''),'!','') as value
FROM (
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.sentence, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) value
  FROM table_name t CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.sentence) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.sentence, ' ', '')))
 ORDER BY value

) AS x
GROUP BY x.value

) AS y
GROUP BY value
```

Here is the full working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17481a/1

First we do a query to extract all words as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19073575/5315239) by @peterm(follow his instructions if you want to customize the total number of words processed). Then we convert that into a sub-query and then we  `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` the value of each word, and then make another query on top of that to `GROUP BY` not grouped words cases where accompanied signs might be present. ie: hello = hello! with a `REPLACE`

Answer (score -1):

Below is the simple solution for the case when you need to count certain word occurrences, not the complete statistics:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `words` WHERE `row1` LIKE '%how%';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `words` WHERE `row1` LIKE '%you%';
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but this thing is very basic which I already know. Likewise if I have 200 words to search, I will have to run 200 queries, which I don't want.

Comment: @Minras: Looking at the example given above, you can see that your solution gives an incorrect answer.  It returns 1 per row that has the searched-for word, not 1 per occurrence of word.  Your second query gives 2, but it *should* give 3.