# SQL Query to get a row which has comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL Table which has rows like this

```
--------------------
 id   promocode
--------------------
 1    test,test2
 2    test,test3
 3    test2,test3
```

Now I want to select rows which has value 'test' in the 'promocode' column.
    
When I use

```
SELECT id from table WHERE promocode LIKE 'test'
```

it is returning all the rows because all the rows have the string 'test' in them. But I want only 1 & 2 rows because only those two rows have the exact value I need. Can anyone help me with the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT id from table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('test', promocode) > 0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8caf4/1)

**Note:**

Storing comma separated lists in columns is almost ever asking for trouble. Please consider normalizing your database.

Comment: It worked for me Thankyou so much. 
What is the problem when I use comma separated values? How can I store more than one value in single field?

Comment: If it worked for you, please consider mark this as answer. To your next question: you shouldn't want to :-) Use another table with at least two columns: `id` and `promocode`. The id column is referencing the other table and for every promocode you insert a new row.

Comment: @raghuveer999 You could look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031397/merge-two-colums-multiple-rows-ignoring-duplicates-mysql to get the latest problem with such multiple values I helped to solve.

Comment: @raghueveer999, comma separated values defeats the purpose of a db. Each column has some meaning and is meant to store a value. Stuffing 3 values in 1 column, slapping a comma in between, is a poor design. I'm assuming you're going to say 'each entry could have more than 1 promo code' So you either a) design a table with cols pcode1, pcode2, ... pcoden (there has to be some MAX), define pcode 1 as NOT NULL and the rest as NULL (meaning they may not be utilized). The 2nd option is to go with your current id, promocode and have multiple entries per id: 1|test   1|test2   2|test   2|test3...