# mysql find numbers in query that are NOT in table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a simple way to compare a list of numbers in my query to a column in a table to return the ones that are NOT in the db?

I have a comma separated list of numbers (1,57, 888, 99, 76, 490, etc etc) that I need to compare to the number column in a table in my DB. SOME of those numbers are in the table, some are not. I need the query to return those that are in my comma separated list, but are NOT in the DB...

Comment: `select * from table where number not in (1,2,3,4,5)` should do what you are looking for if I understand you correctly

Comment: no, I need the numbers from MY LIST that are NOT in the DB returned. There will be nothing from the DB returned

Comment: oh, I see. you are basically looking for a diff. you are better of doing the diff in your code, mysql will be slow at figuring this out for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would put the list of numbers to be checked in a table of their own, then use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to check whether they exist in the table to be queried. See this [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/645c5/4) for an example of how this might be accomplished:

If you're comfortable with this syntax, you can even avoid putting into a temp table:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS mycolumn
   UNION
  SELECT 2
   UNION
  SELECT 3
   UNION
  SELECT 4
   UNION
  SELECT 5
   UNION
  SELECT 6
   UNION
  SELECT 7
  ) a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM mytable b
                     WHERE b.mycolumn = a.mycolumn )
```

**UPDATE per comments from OP**

If you can insert your very long list of numbers into a table, then query as follows to get the numbers that are not found in the other table:

```
SELECT mynumber
  FROM mytableof37000numbers a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM myothertable b
                     WHERE b.othernumber = a.mynumber)
```

Alternately

```
SELECT mynumber
  FROM mytableof37000numbers a
 WHERE a.mynumber NOT IN ( SELECT b.othernumber FROM myothertable b )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think MySQL has a method of taking a comma-delimited list and turning it into a virtual table. In Oracle one might use `CONNECT BY`.

Comment: looks like input is `CSV`. But clearly this the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Don't understand the use of UNION here, can you explain? my list of numbers is 37000 long btw, above I was just giving an example.

Comment: Oh I am just using `UNION` to build a temp virtual table. If your list is 37,000 numbers long, put it in a table of its own (that would be the "a" in the query above).

Comment: you are awesome, that solved it (after I imported the numbers to a new table and ran your query)

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you are looking for.

Convert your `CSV` to rows using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. Use `NOT IN` operator to find the values which is not present in `DB`

Then Convert the result back to `CSV` using `Group_Concat`.

```
select group_concat(value) from(
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.a, ',', n.n), ',', -1) value
  FROM csv t CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.a) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.a, ',', '')))) ou
where value not in (select a from db)
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07405/3)

`CSV TO ROWS` referred from this [**ANSWER**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row)

Comment: I don't understand the use of UNION here and why 9 of them?

Comment: @Stephen It is just a tally table to get 1 to 100 rows. you may have to increase it based on the max value in you `CSV`

Answer (score -1):

You could use the 'IN' clause of MySQL. Maybe check this out [IN clause tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Comment: how would I use the IN clause to return those numbers from my list that are not in the DB?

Comment: I don't know how that would help... I need the numbers from MY LIST that are NOT in the DB returned. There will be nothing from the DB returned