# Get unique values from MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following information in a MySQL column:

```
**rubros**
Internet
Internet, Diseño
Arquitectura, Construcción
Textiles
```

And I need to get an array of individual ítems in that list, something like this:

```
array('Internet','Diseño','Arquitectura','Construcción','Textiles');
```

Is there an easy way to do this with PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: You should normalize your database design.

Comment: select your field, then while fetching do an `explode()` to split into separate values... then after you're done that, rebuild your db with a properly normalized design. once you've done that, your question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: This isn't a database I set up or am allowed to modify. Is there a way to do this without changing it's design?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row.  After you have your column split, then SELECT distinct values from it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc B suggest, assuming the DB query result is in $values, something like this would do the job:

```
$result = array();
foreach($values as $value) $result = array_merge($result, explode(", ", $value));
```

Comment: aarrhh, please use brackets and line breaks on foreach, it hurts my eyes... !