# Join statement for multiple values in the same column separated by comma

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, join, datatable

I have 2 tables as follows:-

Products

```
   Product_name |  category_id

   Nutella      |  1,2
   Milk         |  3,4
```

Categories

```
  cat_id        | name
     1          | dessert
     2          | chocolate
     3          | dairy
     4          | milk
```

I am using datatable with server side processing using [SSP](http://74.207.246.202/ssp/example/) library to display the products table.

I need to make join statement that get me the categories for each product since the category column contains comma separated multiple values!

Is there anyway I can do it using MYSQL?

**EDIT**

Expected output

```
 Product_name |  category_id

   Nutella      |  dessert,chocolate
   Milk         |  diary,milk
```

Comment: which RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming as SQL Server, First, You can use the CTE to get rows from comma separated categories ids into rows, then using INNER JOIN on cat_id, you can get the desired result.

<kbd>[SEE DEMO SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e386b/10)</kbd>

```
;WITH CTEProduct (Product_name,category_id) 
AS
(
SELECT A.Product_name,  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS category_id  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT Product_name,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(category_id, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  Products
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
) 

Select CTEProduct.category_id,CTEProduct.Product_name,Categories.name 
From CTEProduct 
     INNER JOIN Categories ON CTEProduct.category_id = Categories.cat_id
```

**EDIT:-** For MYSQL, we have to follow the same approach, convert comma separated string to multiple rows then INNER JOIN. I does not know much about How to separated comma separated string to rows in MYSQL so [Refer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row). I utilized the same answer here.

<kbd>[SEE DEMO MYSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaffc/19)</kbd>

```
Select tablename.Product_name,GROUP_CONCAT(Categories.name) name
From (
SELECT Product_name,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.category_id, ',', n.n), ',', -1) category_id
  FROM Products t CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.category_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.category_id, ',', '')))
  ) tablename
  INNER JOIN Categories ON tablename.category_id = Categories.cat_id
  GROUP BY tablename.Product_name;
```

Comment: Are you sure, you specify previously in your question that you are using MYSQL?

Comment: Actually I update the tags after I saw your response, sorry for that. Thanks so much for your help but is there any way to get the return values for each product in one row?

Comment: Update your question with expected output, then I have better idea.

Comment: modify query and DEMO with desired result

Comment: do you mean your query? It's so difficult for me to understand and update