# select data with separate

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in mysqli table store like that:

```
-----------------------------
-           skill           -
-----------------------------
- teaching,training         -
-----------------------------
- IT,web programming        -
-----------------------------
- construction, Business    -
-----------------------------
```

I have data like that and I want to select data that show result like :

> teaching
>
> training
>
> construction
>
> web programming
>
> Networking
>
> IT
>
> Bussiness

How can I use `mysql` to select with that result ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row

Answer (score 0):

Use normal select data, then use spli string each row with "," as separator.

[Split String](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_split.asp)

or u can use explode

[Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Sorry, i won't give u the code. You should learn it by yourself. :D

Comment: thanks you for that. can you give me some example code of this ?

Comment: @Reaksmeyse Can you show us the code what have you done so far?

Comment: just use normal query like "Select job_name from joblist"
then when u fetch each row with mysqi_fetch_row
use str_split to split each row data.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_split.asp