# MySQL distinct word that separated by space from a single column

Tags: mysql, distinct

Let's say i have a column for tags. This tags is separated by space.

```
|tags                  |
|apple banana melon    |
|apple banana pineapple|
|apple melon pineapple |
```

I would like to get all the word in column tags, separated it by space and remove the duplicate word. So i will get output like this:

```
|unique_tags|
|apple      |
|banana     |
|melon      |
|pineapple  |
```

How to do this in mysql?

Comment: Select and separate all the tags; put the results into a temporary table, then select distinct from the temporary table.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row - using _SELECT DISTINCT ..._ would eliminate duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should better refactor your database schema.

But I see many questions like this and I prefer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows/17942691#17942691) solution.

If you agree you can adapt it to your case this way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fd5e/7

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1) tag
FROM
  numbers 
INNER JOIN t1
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(t1.tags)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t1.tags, ' ', ''))>=numbers.n-1
```

Mention that you have to create `numbers` table with number of records and consecutive values till max number values you expect in your `tags` field list.

Comment: this is more awesome, without additional table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a213e4/1

Comment: really ?? `SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4` you like this solution? son if you will have 10 elements or 20? your query will looks terrible. I really prefer to create one simple table  and keep query readable. But that is up to you :-)