# SQL parse a long varchar field out with parameter/value pairs

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

Our application is running on MySQL 5.6.21, and for every transaction, it writes out an entry into a Log table. The primary field I am interested in is a long varchar field, and it basically has the full URL that is passed in to our application. This data field can have any number of parameter/value pairs in it, that are separated by an ampersand &. I am trying to come up with a way to parse them out, so that we can report on this data.

Here's an example record:
    sessionId=LongSessionIdWeCanIgnore&serverurl=https://www.theurl.com/bla/bla&parameter1=123456789&param2=23456789&par3=987654&p4=abcdef123&parameterlongname6=ABCDEFG

So from this field, I'd like to have a SQL statement/function that separates it out as follows:

```
Parameter                Value
---------------          ----------------------
serverUrl                https://www.theurl.com/bla/bla
parameter1               123456789
param2                   23456789
par3                     987654
p4                       abcdef123
parameterlongname6       ABCDEFG
```

So as you can see, this SQL needs to be able to loop through, and for each ampersand that it sees, pull out the parameter name (from the & to the =), and the value that is after the = sign (from the = to the next &). I've got the SQL worked out that is "hard-coded" for one parameter, but I want to avoid this, as we have over 300 different parameters possible, and I don't want to have to write separate code for each one. Example SQL below for the hard-coded one I've got so far:

```
select
substr(ParameterString,(instr(ParameterString, '&parameter1=')+12), (locate('&', ParameterString, instr(ParameterString, '&parameter1=')+12)) -  (instr(ParameterString, '&parameter1=')+12))
from TestLogTable
where ParameterString like '%&parameter1=%';
```

Again, I don't like this method as it's got to be hardcoded with the number 12, as that is the length of '&parameter1='.

I'm hoping some of the SQL gurus here can help me get this thing more dynamic and automated?? Sample SQL below to create a test table with some test data.

Thank you!!

```
create table TestLogTable (ParameterString varchar(32768));

insert into TestLogTable (ParameterString) values ('sessionId=LongSessionIdWeCanIgnore&serverurl=https://www.theurl.com/bla/bla&parameter1=123456789&param2=23456789&par3=987654&p4=abcdef123&parameterlongname6=ABCDEFG');
insert into TestLogTable (ParameterString) values ('sessionId=LongSessionIdWeCanIgnore&serverurl=https://www.theurl2.com/bla/bla&parameter5=123456789&param6=23456789&par7=987654&p8=abcdef123&parameterlongname9=ABCDEFG');
insert into TestLogTable (ParameterString) values ('sessionId=LongSessionIdWeCanIgnore&serverurl=https://www.theurl2.com/bla/bla&parameter5=123456123&param6=23456789123&par7=987654123&p8=abcdef123123&parameterlongname9=ABCDEFG123123');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is basically the opposite of the mysql `Group_conat()` function--instead of concating together a set, break it apart on a separator.

There's no easy one line query that covers this if you don't know the exact number of parameters.  If you know the max number of parameters, you can write something like: [SQL split comma separated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row).

I suggest what you really want to do is write a procedure if you don't know the exact limit or it may change.

Here's another SO question that covers how you can achieve this with stored procedures:  ["Reverse GROUP_CONCAT" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308669/reverse-group-concat-in-mysql)