# select multi url from one column in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with "content" column store forum post, there is one or more url in one record of "content" field, I want to get all the url in the “content" column, one url in one row, I use below code

```
select substr(`content`, locate(`content`,"http://"))
```

it work for one url in one record, get a list of url like

- http://www.google.com
- http://www.facebook.com
- ...

it only get the first url if there are more than one url in the record.

how to fix it?

Comment: Sure would be easier if the data was normalized so that values were stored independently of one another...

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows but the way to go is as @David said above - normalize the data first.

Comment: it's normal some posts has more than one urls, like reply some newbie's question, some users will reply will some links, so there are 2 or 3 links in one post.

Comment: I'm new to mysql but I read that post the text in the sample is seperated by comma, in my case I think I can identify the url by "http://" or <a href=" but no idea how to get the length of the url due to many different ending in url.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it is to try:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(substr(`content`, locate(`content`,"http://"))) FROM your_table;
```

which would concatenate all URLs to a single string and carry on from there - maybe you can split it in the code rather than require the DB to do it. Otherwise you can hack on using an auxiliary table of integers 1-n: [SQL split comma separated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row)