# PHP Table With Comma [delete this]

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image]

Here i get mos popular hashtags (mos used hashtags) but problem is with comma my query show this:

```
Popular hashtags: 
#q7 (2)
#q9 (2)
#q7 , #q0 (1)
#q0 (1)
```

I want this:

```
Popular hashtags: 
#q7 (3 times )
#q9 (2 times)
#q0 (2 times)
```

my code:

```
$query_result = mysqli_query($Connection, "select hashtag, count(hashtag) as cnt
from tricks
group by hashtag
order by cnt desc limit 5");

$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
   $results[] = "{$row['hashtag']} ({$row['cnt']})";
}
echo "Popular hashtags: </br>", implode("</br>", $results);
```

Comment: print_r($results);what it shows?

Comment: show this: Popular hashtags: 
#q7 (2)
#q9 (2)
#q7 , #q0 (1)
#q0 (1)   but is incorrect

Comment: beacouse #q7 is used 3times #q9 2times and #q0 times

Comment: ideally you would store the tags in separate records rather than comma-separated in the same string; it's much easier to work with if they're separate.

Comment: Simba understates the case. It's not just more difficult when a relational database holds more than value in an attribute, it's WRONG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php solution:

```
$query_result = mysqli_query($Connection, 
                  "SELECT hashtag FROM tricks");             

$popularHashtags = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {

  $hashtags = explode(',', $row['hashtag']);

  foreach($hashtags as $hashtag) {
      $hashtag = trim($hashtag);

      if (!empty($hashtag)) {

        if (!isset($popularHashtags[$hashtag])) {
          $popularHashtags[$hashtag] = 0;
        }

        $popularHashtags[$hashtag]++;
      } 
  }
}


arsort($popularHashtags);

// for showing popular hashtags

echo "Popular hashtags: <br />";

foreach($popularHashtags as $hashtag => $total) {
  echo $hashtag . " ( " . $total . " ) <br />";
}
```

Comment: thanks so much but now show me this error: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row'

Comment: I have made some changes. Could you check again? @ShkurtaAbazi

Comment: now work but not show correct :( see image: http://i.imgur.com/62IjVTw.png

Comment: You have to add !empty check, see my changes @ShkurtaAbazi.

Comment: now work correct thank you so much but how to remove array i want to echo only hashtag name and used times thanks ??? http://i.imgur.com/pQLuFaB.png

Comment: np :) @ShkurtaAbazi

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of hastags contained in the field, you can use the  [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function, or you can see this answer [MySQL split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two#answer-2696901) to split your field.

Something like this (I have not a MySQL instance):

```
SELECT hastag as T1 FROM tricks WHERE hastag NOT LIKE '%,%' -- Take the Hastag without separator in it
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(hashtag, ',', 1) as T1 FROM tricks WHERE hastag LIKE '%,%' -- Take the first Hastag (before separator)
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(hashtag, ',', 2) as T1 FROM tricks WHERE hastag LIKE '%,%' -- Take the second Hastag (before separator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
select count(*) as total, hashtag FROM (
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(hashtag, ',', n.n), ',', -1) hashtag
  FROM table CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(hashtag) - LENGTH(REPLACE(hashtag, ',', ''))) ORDER BY hashtag ) alias GROUP by hashtag
```

Took the help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row) answer. Hope this helps you