# Select unique values from Database

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

Im having some troubles showing the unique values from my database.
As an example, I have this very simple test table:

[image]

Where you can see that there is a duplicated value on the Tags column, named intro.

I would like to echo all of the `UNIQUE` tags, and I've tried with the `DISTINCT` command, but I might be doing something wrong.

This is my actual query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM blog
```

But this gives me ALL of the tags.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing tags in a comma-delimited list.  Instead, use a table with one row per `blogId` and `tag`.

Comment: ^ I was just going to say something to that effect.

Comment: Agree, also - I am assuming this is `mysql`, if that is the case, could you tag the question with the proper DBMS? It may aid in finding a solution to your current problem... aside from redesigning your `blog` table.

Comment: and those spaces in there count for something also. You're best to start over following @GordonLinoff 's suggestion.

Comment: Also, there is a fairly helpful question/answer out here already. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row discussing the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function and splitting your comma separated list into individual rows within a query.

Comment: You don't have duplicates. "intro" is not the same as "intro , php , warning , errors"

Comment: I think you should first separate the comma separated values and then find the unique the values.

Comment: About all those separations between my tags (intro , whatever , ) I just wrote that to test a different approach to the DISTINCT command. I mean, I've also tried to do the query without the spaces wich I'll remove right now. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the image there are just to rows in the table, one contains "intro" and the other contains "intro, php, warning, errors".
If so, there are not the same.

I think you try to use a row for each value.
To do it you should insert each value in a separated sentence, or in the same but using different rows, something like:

> insert into blog(tags) values ("intro"),values ("intro"),values ("php")

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll reorganize my data structure as said on the comments.