# How to retrieve multiple data that store inside the same database column?

Tags: mysql, sql

My database is like

```
Name  |  IC   |   Item
--------------------------
lee   |  xxx  |   pear,bear
--------------------------
ron   |  xxx   |  apple,dog
```

what should I do to retrieve the 4 values contained in the column "Item" and then separate them?

Comment: What output do you actually want?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the name string in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad database design

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: hmm..its part of the project database. I cant edit or change the design half way now. So is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only two items separated by comma in Item? Or it may vary?

LE: you can use this [SQL split comma separated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row)
LLE: just played around with that and this what I've done:

```
create table myTable(name varchar(7), ic varchar(7), item varchar(200));

insert into myTable(name,ic,item) values ('lee','xxx','pear,bear');
insert into myTable(name,ic,item) values ('ron','xxx','apple,dog');
insert into myTable(name,ic,item) values ('a','xxx','gamma');
insert into myTable(name,ic,item) values ('b','xxx','a,b,c,d');

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.item, ',', n.n), ',', -1) value
FROM myTable t CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
    FROM 
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
        ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.item) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.item, ',', '')))
ORDER BY value;
```