# Mysql group by query with where condition

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have a table with folowing structure

```
CREATE TABLE `ABC` (
    `SNO` int(11) NOT NULL,<br>
    `ID1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ID2` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `TYPE` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `TIME` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`SNO`),
 UNIQUE KEY `IND1` (`ID1`,`ID2`),
 KEY `RECEIVER` (`ID2`)
)
```

I want to get `ID2's` grouped by `ID1's` which have a certain `TYPE 'A'` .If no `ID1` `ID2` combination have `TYPE 'A'` then get all other ID1 ID2 combinations.
I have used the following query-:

```
SELECT 
   ID1, 
   GROUP_CONCAT( ID2 ) , 
   GROUP_CONCAT( TYPE ) 
FROM CONTACTS
  WHERE TIME >  '2017-08-11 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY ID1
```

Now this gives me `TYPE` as a group concatenated string which i have to operate upon to get those `ID1`,`ID2` combinations with `TYPE 'A'`.

Output-:

```
ID1    |  group_concat(ID2) | group_concat(TYPE) |
144111 | 556,3577,254389    |  A,I,I             |
```

Can there be a way to get this done with Mysql itself without the need of further group_concatenated string?

Would using temporary tables be a better way?

Comment: Try to create temp table and store data's temporary table in your same query..

Comment: Can you also post your expected result based on the output that you have provided? Maybe this [Split Comma Separated Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073500/sql-split-comma-separated-row) thread might help please read it.